# showing ePUB file in jsp page

Tags: java, epub

Could you please guide me on how to open ePUB file in jsp? I understand, I need to call some third party tool like Adobe Digital for ePUB. But how to embed Adobe Digital with JSP page?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Epublib for Java

http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib

For other options you can visit the previously discussed question below

[making ePub with Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429242/making-epub-with-java-api)